# paste option for edittext

Tags: java, android

I have an edittext and I would like to paste some text in it. I can copy the text from some web page but I am not able to paste the text in my edittext control.How can I enable my edittext to paste some text.Here is my main.xml for edittext ;

```
enter code here

<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/enter"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight= "2"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/black"
/>
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to do it programmatically?

Comment: yes.if user places finger inside the edittext, how can I show option of paste?

Comment: Well, the user should be able to see the paste option, if he presses and hold the edit text. Doesn't that work?

Comment: in my ediitext that option is not showing. What am I missing here?

Comment: Thats a bit hard to believe. You don't see any popup when you long tap on the Editext? Strange. Which emulator/device are you running?

Comment: i am sorry about that. I just tested and it works. New to android development.

Comment: @KumarBibek what about copy option? Why it's not showing sometimes and how to enable that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is on Android 4.4.2 Samsung S4;

Documentation for [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) says that:

> To allow users to copy some or all of the TextView's value and paste
>   it somewhere else, set the XML attribute **android:textIsSelectable** to
>   "true" or call **setTextIsSelectable(true)**. The textIsSelectable flag
>   allows users to make selection gestures in the TextView, which in turn
>   triggers the system's built-in copy/paste controls.

There is also another Textview attribure called [android:cursorVisible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3acursorVisible) which determines if the system should be invoked about the copy/paste callbacks.

By default I believe both of these are true and selection/copy/paste mechanics are already enabled. I could not change that behaviour by using `android:textIsSelectable="false"` but if I set `android:cursorVisible="false"` initially you can't paste anything inside the EditText. Only after you type something in, cursor and selection behaviour becomes enabled again. Maybe this should be handled inside the code rather than in the layout xmls, or it might be related to `android:inputType` which also did not make a difference for me.

So try setting `android:cursorVisible="true"` in your EditText's layout xml if paste is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

According to your problem if you copied some data any where in your system and you want to paste it in some specific variable, like Edit TextBox, Textview etc, then this code will surely help you.

```
 ClipboardManager clipMan = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(v.getContext().CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
 myEdtTxt.setText(clipMan.getText());
```

Note:- here the clipMan object will store the data whenever copied process take place and we will return that data from that object and will set it,

Answer (score 3):

To enable the standard copy/paste for TextView, U can choose one of the following:
Change in layout file: 
Either add below property to your TextView

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

and   In your Java class write this line to set it programmatically.

```
myTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

if fragment try with

```
mContext.myTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

And long press on the TextView you can see copy/paste action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `inputType="text"` for the `EditText` field