# How to get listener of the share in the menu copy/cut of the edittext in android

Tags: android, menu, android-edittext, listener, share

Does anyone know how I can capture the click on the share button from EditText's copy / cut menu?

[image]

Comment: Implement an `ACTION_SEND` activity responding to the `text/plain` MIME type, probably.

Comment: Great! Thanks @CommonsWare!

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. When I choose that option, I get a chooser with the activities that I would expect for ACTION_SEND.

Comment: But I want to launch an ad activity when I click on it. How to do this?

Comment: I do not know what "an ad activity" is. I have no idea why any user would want "an ad activity" to be an option from the `EditText` share option. And I have no idea what is preventing you from writing your own activity with your own `<intent-filter>` to support `ACTION_SEND` for `text/plain`.

Comment: I solved my problem using:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668011/how-to-detect-the-paste-event-in-editext-of-the-application). I just created a custom EditText.