# How to get last text when a user paste it in the edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, copy-paste

I have an edittext an it have many words in it. After I paste it some keywords and I want to catch only pasted keywords.

I find different solution but its only gave me text is pasted or cut. I want keywords too.

[How to detect the paste event in editext of the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668011/how-to-detect-the-paste-event-in-editext-of-the-application)

Is there any solution like swift or Do we have to hack again.

And sorry for my terrible english.

"Test Test Test" -> paste new -> "Test Test Pasted Text Here Test"

I want to get "Pasted Text Here"

Comment: Oops! Can't understand please provide screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a custom EditText that can catch paste event. For that, it will need to override `onTextContextMenuItem(int id)`

Something like that is enough :

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    UpdateListener listener;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public void setUpdateListener(UpdateListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
        boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);

        switch (id){
            case android.R.id.cut :
                if(listener != null) listener.onCut();
                break;
            case android.R.id.copy :
                if(listener != null) listener.onCopy();
                break;
            case android.R.id.paste :
                if(listener != null) listener.onPaste();
        }

        return consumed;
    }

    interface UpdateListener{
        void onCut();
        void onCopy();
        void onPaste();
    }
}
```

Then, in activity, you have to implement the interface given by this custom EditText

```
editText = findViewById(R.id.textview2);
editText.setUpdateListener(new MyEditText.UpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCut() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCut: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCopy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCopy: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaste() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPaste: ");
        // triggered when code is pasted
    }
});
```

If i understand well you want that when the user paste somethinig, it erases what was written and paste the text.
In `onPaste()` :

```
@Override
public void onPaste() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPaste: ");
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    String pasteData = "";
    //check if something present in clipboard, and check if it is text
    if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip() && clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
        ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        pasteData = item.getText().toString();
        editText.setText(pasteData);
    }
}
```